# "there was no" vs. "there had been no"

Tags: word-usage

Here is part of [Early Responses to the Periodic System](https://books.google.com/books?id=zb1TBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT44&dq=%22up%20to%20that%20time%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-id_9gtnqAhVFsp4KHQpwDYkQ6AEwBnoECAkQAg)

> Alekseev also noted that because **there had been no** translation of Mendeleev's textbook into a foreign language up to that time, chemists in other countries had formed a superficial and often incorrect view of the periodic.

It seems simpler to say it like this

> Alekseev also noted that because **there was no** translation ...

Do they mean the same thing?

I looked them up on [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there%20were%20no%2Cthere%20was%20no%2Cthere%20had%20been%20no%2C%20there%20wasn%27t%2C%20there%20weren%27t&year_start=1800&corpus=26&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20were%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20had%20been%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20were%20not%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthere%20were%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20had%20been%20no%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20was%20not%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20were%20not%3B%2Cc0), though I'm not sure whether it helps in this situation.

[image]

Comment: Does it help you to understand if you compare the following two cases?: 1) "No one translated the book" and 2) "No one has translated the book", In (2), the emphasis is on the fact that no translation exists today, because in the entire time since the original book was written, no one translated it. If you understand this difference, then you only need to consider that in the text you quoted, the time of no translation existing is in the past, not the present.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means the same thing with your change only because it includes "up to that time". The 'had been no' emphasizes the period from when the book was written until the time Alekseev referred to.

Comment: Thank you. By "only because", does the answer emphasize that the phrase "up to that time" is the key part, without which my sentence doesn't mean the same thing?

Comment: ThomasW: In some sense, yes. "Because" and "had been" are related, because both show that an earlier event caused a later situation.

Comment: @ThomasW: Usually past versus perfect ("was” vs. ”has been”) mean the same events, but the difference gives information about how an author interprets the causes of the events. Intention, not meaning, is what affects a choice to use on or the other.